# Convert CSS3 rotateY to PHP Imagick::distortImage

Tags: php, css, imagick

I have an image that gets `rotateY(-54deg)` on the front-end and I need to rotate it the same way on PHP using `Imagick::distortImage`

```
$image->distortImage(Imagick::DISTORTION_PERSPECTIVE, $controlPoints, true);
```

Is there an easy way to convert the `-54deg` to the `$controlPoints` that `distortImage()` needs?

Comment: why dont use Imagick::rotateImage?

Comment: @NicolòCozzani Because I don't want to simple rotate the image, I need to change the perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think there is any (easy) way to do this.

The `Imagick::DISTORTION_PERSPECTIVE` is used to distort the images using `perspective projection` which requires 8 precalculated coefficients.

From the [imagemagick docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#distort)

> You can get these coefficients by looking at the -verbose output of a
>   'Perspective' distortion, or by calculating them yourself. If the last
>   two perspective scaling coefficients are zero, the remaining 6
>   represents a transposed 'Affine Matrix'.

I dont think `-54deg` has got enough data inherently in it to decipher these 8 coefficients. You will have to do this the hard way, sorry :)

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks.